# adding custome dashboard in zabbix monitoring tool screens

Tags: dashboard, zabbix

we are using zabbix monitoring tool to monitor server health. can we also add some custom dashboard in zabbix where I can add some custom monitoring measure like no of people login to my application, no of order made etc to display in that dashboard as I have only one screen where I can display a dashboard or zabbix monitoring tool

Answer (score 0):

The concept is called [screen](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/visualisation/screens#adding_elements) in Zabbix and as the manual suggests, you can also add data retrieved from a custom URL, when using the [Resource **URL**](https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.0/manual/config/visualisation/screens/elements#url).

Not sure, however, how well this works in practice and if it's retrieved from the client or server side.

Comment: thanks for your reply I will try this custom url but i dont think it will serve the purpose